# Pop up div with absolute position next to click

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

I am trying to make a right click lead to a div pop up. However, the click will be inside a cesium window, which only lets a div show if it has absolute position. Is it possible to edit the pop up position of a div with absolute position?

Right now, my code looks like this:

```js
var editHandler = newCesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
editHandlersetInputAction(function(e){
  var shapeEditMenu = document.getElementById("shapeEditMenu");
  shapeEditMenu.style.display = "block";
  shapeEditMenu.style.left = e.clientX;
  shapeEditMenu.style.top = e.clientY;
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.RIGHT_CLICK);
```

```css
#shapeEditMenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none:
  top: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shapeEditMenu">
  Line thickness:
  <input type="number"> pt
</div>
```

It doesn't work here because there isn't cesium, but what happens in my actual code is that the div pops up on right click, but always is at the same position, not at the place where you right click.

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: What have you done so far? We can't be of much help without something to work with.

Comment: I added my code, sorry about that!

Comment: At least do the effort to provide an example that does not point to unknown variables and functions. What is newCesium? what is editHandlersetInputAction? What is cesium?

Comment: Nevertheless, I think you are confusing your library's API with the standard browser API. `clientX` and `clientY` properties are only available on [`MouseEvent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). A mouse event can be caught using `element.addEventListener(type, listener)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is some API confusion going on here.  `clientX` is part of browser-native API, not Cesium's API.  Since you're using Cesium's event handling system, you get events from that API.  In this case, you would use `e.position.x` and follow that up with a `+ 'px'` to indicate CSS-pixel units for the stylesheet.

Also you have a few typos here:

- `newCesium.` should be `new Cesium.`
- `editHandlersetInputAction` should be `editHandler.setInputAction`
- `display: none:` should be `display: none;`

Here's a [live Sandcastle demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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) that shows a right-click "Testing" menu show up at the mouse location.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var editHandler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);

editHandler.setInputAction(function(e) {
  var shapeEditMenu = document.getElementById("toolbar");
  shapeEditMenu.textContent = 'Testing';
  shapeEditMenu.style.display = "block";
  shapeEditMenu.style.left = e.position.x + 'px';
  shapeEditMenu.style.top = e.position.y + 'px';
  shapeEditMenu.style.background = 'rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.8)';
  shapeEditMenu.style.border = '1px solid #888';
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.RIGHT_CLICK);

editHandler.setInputAction(function(e) {
  var shapeEditMenu = document.getElementById("toolbar");
  shapeEditMenu.style.display = "none";
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_DOWN);
```